# Why doesn't the finish() method work on my android studio project? 1

Tags: java, android, activity-finish

I'm trying to create a Splash screen and that was successful. However, I want the splash screen to disappear after 3 seconds. In an attempt to achieve this, I used the finish() method which didn't work to any avail. I'm wondering why the finish() method is not working on my app and what I can do to make the Splash Screen disappear in 3 seconds.All help would be greatly appreciated.

```
   package com.pace.carryonsplashpage;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class SplashScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       // setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);
        Intent I = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(I);
            finish();
    }


}
```

Home Activity XML code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".HomeActivity">

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: also please share your `HomeAcitvity` xml code

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this code? It will close the SplashActivity after 3 seconds.

```java
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                                         SecondActivity.class);
                //Intent is used to switch from one activity to another.
                  
                startActivity(i);
                //invoke the SecondActivity.
                  
                finish();
                //the current activity will get finished.
            }
        }, 3000); // 3 seconds
```

Also don't comment the `setContentView()`. You want see anything on the screen without it

Comment: I tried the code that you provided new Handler().postDelayed(() -> { and the compiler is saying that it's an illegal start of expression.

Comment: Also, the compiler is complaining about this line.  },3 * 3000); // 3 seconds